# Force tkinter listbox to highlight item when selected before task is started

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a tkinter listbox, when I select a item it performs a few actions then returns the results, while that is happening the item I selected does not show as selected, is there a way to force it to show selected immediately so it's obvious to the user they selected the correct one while waiting on the returned results? I'm using python 3.4 and I'm on a windows 7 machine.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. I can mark it answered if you add it below.

Answer (score 0):

The item does show as selected right away because the time consuming actions are executed before updating the GUI. You can force the GUI to update before executing the actions by using `window.update_idletasks()`.